# why does bootstrap 4 dropdown and toggle button not work even after installing and importing dependencies?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular7

This is what i have tried!

https://navbarex.stackblitz.io

i have installed bootstrap, jquery and popper.js

and i have imported that in angular.json file

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"              
        ]
```

I've tried same thing on my local machine and it's working fine but why not here in StackBlitz?

Comment: don't use jQuery with Angular... for bootstrap components you have ng-bootstrap, md-bootstrap etc

Comment: in my entire application i have already used normal bootstrap :(